# Subdomain based resources in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain

I am looking for a simple way to replace all my routes matching mydomain.com/resources/xx by xx.mydomain.com with Rails 4.

Would anyone have an idea to do that easily and that would work with nested resources as well?

Thanks, Joris

Answer (score 2):

[**Constraints**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints)

What you're looking for is *constraints* in your routes, specifically that you're looking to use one to determine whether you have a subdomain that you can access

There are a number of resources on how to achieve this:

> - [Basecamp-style subdomains by DHH](http://signalvnoise.com/posts/1512-how-to-do-basecamp-style-subdomains-in-rails)
> - [Subdomains Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3)

The bottom line is that you'll probably have to create a custom subdomai constraint, which you can then use the standard routing structure for:

```
#lib/subdomain.rb
class Subdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    if request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != 'www'
        account = Account.find_by username: request.subdomain
        return true if account # -> if account is not found, return false (IE no route)
    end
  end
end


#config/routes.rb
constraints(Subdomain) do
   get "/", to: "controller#action"
   resources :posts #-> subdomain.domain.com/posts
   ...
end
```

The above is untested - I also found the following with [Rails' documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints):

```
#lib/subdomain.rb
class Subdomain
  def initialize
    @accounts = Account.all
  end

  def matches?(request)
    if request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != 'www'
        @accounts.include?(request.subdomain)
    end
  end
end

#config/routes.rb
constraints: Subdomain.new do
   get "/", to: "controller#action"
   resources :posts #-> subdomain.domain.com/posts
   ...
end
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. But there is no way to tie the subdomain automatically to a parameter, be it to retrieve it in the controllers params[:account_id] (just as I do for now) or to create new paths or urls with the id that will be set as the subdomain? (account_path(@account) would return account_slug.domain.com or account_id.domain.com). That would be nice, but I guess I'll have to change all the routes in the views and variables in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here how I have done it before in a Rails 3 app:

```
  constraints :subdomain => /ambassador/ do
    namespace(:influencer, :path => '/') do
      root :to => 'home#index'
      match 'home' => 'sweepstakes#index', :as => :influencer_home
      resources :sweepstakes
      resources :associates
      resources :widgets
      resources :sessions
      resources :reports do
        resource :member
      end
      match 'faq' => 'info#faq'
    end
  end
```

Be sure to put this block towards the top of the **routes.rb** file so it takes precedence.

You can of course nest your resources in here like normal.